# kerasで時系列データ予想

Tags: python, keras

使用してるデータはfxのgbpjpy日足終値です、大体10年分です

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from keras import models
from keras.layers import LSTM,Dense
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

data=pd.read_csv("1440.csv")

#create data
datax=[]
datay=[]
p=100

for i in range(len(data)-p) :
    datax.append(data["close"][i:i+p])
    datay.append(data["close"][i+p])
    
datax=np.array(datax)
datay=np.array(datay)

#split data
l=int(len(datax)*0.8)
xtrain=datax[:l]
xtest=datax[l:]
ytrain=datay[:l]
ytest=datay[l:]


#normalize data
scal=StandardScaler()
scaly=StandardScaler()
xtrain1=scal.fit_transform(xtrain)
xtest1=scal.fit_transform(xtest)
ytrain1=scaly.fit_transform(ytrain.reshape(len(ytrain),1))
ytest1=scaly.fit_transform(ytest.reshape(len(ytest),1))

#change shape of data
xtrain1=np.reshape(xtrain1,(xtrain1.shape[0],1,xtrain1.shape[1]))
xtest1=np.reshape(xtest1,(xtest1.shape[0],1,xtest1.shape[1]))

#create model
model=models.Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128,activation="tanh",input_shape=(1,p)))
model.add(Dense(128,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1,activation="linear"))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizer="adam")

#learn and plot
result=model.fit(xtrain1,ytrain1,batch_size=100,epochs=100)
yp=model.predict(xtest1)
yp=scaly.inverse_transform(yp).flatten()
plt.plot(yp)
plt.plot(ytest)
```

[image: 結果]

Comment: 本文に質問文がありません。何に困っているか明確に記述しましょう。またどうなっているとよいのか自分が期待している見え方やゴールも明確に記述しましょう

Comment: コメントありがとうございます、次から気をづけてわかりやすく質問内容記述します。

Comment: ぜひ今後同様の問題を抱えてやってきた人たちのために、今から本文中をわかりやすく質問を内容を記述しましょう。現時点ではクローズになってしまっているのが再オープンされてるでしょう。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問とデータが明確ではありませんが、察するに、損失関数が間違っているのだと考えられます。
分類問題ではないので、回帰のための損失関数を使う必要があります。

https://keras.io/api/losses/regression_losses/

このために一般的に使われるのは、MeanSquaredErrorです。

```py
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="nadam")
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます、すごく助かりました。以降は質問内容を明確に記述するよう気を付けます。